# Which is the most elegant way to save a multi dimensional string array in C#?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I am looking for a better way or most elegant way to save multidimension string array.
This is the scenario:
instead of saving a list with languages in sql table I want to save it in an array/ararylist/object so I can access it quicker. 
It would contain:

```
{
{"en-US", "English"},
{"ro-RO", "Romanian"},
{"pt-PT", "Portuguese"}
}
```

This list might contain many other things.
Please excuse me but I did not found any solution yet on Stack.

Comment: In what way are you going to access it? Just select culture name by code or something more complex?

Comment: Save it where? To disk? Just keep it in memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)?

e.g.

```
Dictionary<string, string> english = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
  {"en-US", "English"},
  {"ro-RO", "Romanian"},
  {"pt-PT", "Portuguese"}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Dictionary` class. here's an example

```
Dictionary<String, String> lDict = new Dictionary<String, String>();
lDict.Add("en-US", "English");
...
lDict["en-US"]; // == "English"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to load it during runtime and save it in a seperate file i suggest looking at serialization

Answer (score 1):

You have not detailed on your intent or usage of the list that you wish to store. In case, this is a look-up table kind of data and you wish to look up for something, you can look at Dictionary. Please refer to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) for details on Dictionary.

In your case, considering you have a pair of strings and you want to get the second element in the pair using the first element of the pair, you can have a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, String> myDict = new Dictionary<string, String>();
//add the elements or members
myDict.Add("en-US", "English");
//TO DO: Add the rest of the items

//Get the second element for a member
string Lang = myDict["en-US"];
```

But if this needs persistence, you shall have to manage the serialization and deserialization as well.